# Flutter:MainActivity cannot be converted to FlutterEngine in Java Native code

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart, android-native-library

I am trying to create a plugin for Flutter in Java. I am trying to pass the `Android activity` parameter in my main `Java` class.

This is my native code:

```
package com.example.trsurveys;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import android.app.Activity;

import io.flutter.embedding.engine.plugins.FlutterPlugin;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodCall;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel.MethodCallHandler;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel.Result;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry.Registrar;

import theoremreach.com.theoremreach.TheoremReach;


public class TrsurveysPlugin implements FlutterPlugin, MethodCallHandler {
  private MethodChannel channel;
  private Registrar registrar;
  private Activity activity;

  @Override
  public void onAttachedToEngine(@NonNull FlutterPluginBinding flutterPluginBinding) {
    channel = new MethodChannel(flutterPluginBinding.getFlutterEngine().getDartExecutor(), "trsurveys");
    channel.setMethodCallHandler(this);
  }

When I try to debug my app it shows me the following errors

    private TrsurveysPlugin(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

  public static void registerWith(Registrar registrar) {
    final MethodChannel channel = new MethodChannel(registrar.messenger(), "trsurveys");
    channel.setMethodCallHandler(new TrsurveysPlugin(registrar.activity()));
  }

  @Override
  public void onMethodCall(@NonNull MethodCall call, @NonNull Result result) {
    if (call.method.equals("init")) {
      String apiKey = call.argument("apiKey");
      TheoremReach.initWithApiKeyAndUserIdAndActivityContext(apiKey, "USER_ID", activity);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onDetachedFromEngine(@NonNull FlutterPluginBinding binding) {
    channel.setMethodCallHandler(null);
  }
}
```

When I try to debug my app I get the following errors:

```
error: constructor TrsurveysPlugin in class TrsurveysPlugin cannot be applied to given types;
    flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new com.example.trsurveys.TrsurveysPlugin());
                                   ^
  required: Activity
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

...path/Downloads/TheoremReach-error/example/android/app/src/main/java/com/example/trsurveys_example/MainActivity.java:11: error: incompatible types: MainActivity cannot be converted to FlutterEngine
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this);
                                       ^
```

This is the code that appears in my `GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java` file.

```
package io.flutter.plugins;

import androidx.annotation.Keep;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine;

@Keep
public final class GeneratedPluginRegistrant {
  public static void registerWith(@NonNull FlutterEngine flutterEngine) {
    flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new com.example.trsurveys.TrsurveysPlugin());
  }
}
```

While making the Plugin I have tried deleting the GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java file but every time it gets generated with the same configurations.

Comment: Is there any progress about this issue?

Answer (score 10):

This happened to me when upgrading a repository from older flutter version to the newer one. I followed the official [flutter link](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Upgrading-pre-1.12-Android-projects) for the migration.

I made appropriate changes on the android manifest file. Namely:

1. Remove `android:name` attribute from `<application>` tag
2. Change `android:name` of the single `<activity>` to  `android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity"`
3. Add `<meta-data android:name="flutterEmbedding" android:value="2"/>` as child of  tag

However, I didn't change any code on the `MainActivity` which caused the error. The `MainActivity` was using older imports which was incompatible with the above three changes.

Final manifest file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="co.appbrewery.magic8ball">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<application
    android:label="magic_8_ball"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
    <activity
        android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <meta-data android:name="flutterEmbedding" android:value="2"/>
        <meta-data
            android:name="io.flutter.app.android.SplashScreenUntilFirstFrame"
            android:value="true" />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Deleting the `MainActivity` resolved the issue for me.

Comment: Worked for me too! Good to see another fella that is trying to tackle with the same Flutter course that I do :)

Answer (score 1):

Open your project manifest file and remove this Lines

```html
meta-data
android:name=”flutterEmbedding”
android:value=”2″
```

Then build and run it again.

Comment: After removing these lines, I get another error.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this problem with the following steps:
goto android-> app-> src-> main-> java-> com-> (your package)-> MainActivity.java. Now comment this line:

```
public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {
  /*@Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this);
  }*/
```

}
Now your MainActivity will look like this:

```
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity;
public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {
}
```